# Recursively call a function object

Tags: c++, function-object

How do I call a function object from within itself? Seems I cannot use `this`. Example:

```
class factorial {
  public:
  int operator()(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
      return 1;
    return n * ??(n-1);
  }
};
```

What do I place at `??`?

Comment: What about `(*this)`?

Comment: Also, `this->operator()(n-1);`

Comment: @Borgleader: He's following a functor pattern, which calls for a non-`static` `operator()()`.  It's not always valuable to add modifiers such as `static` just because you can, for this particular version of this particular functor.

Comment: added `public:` per the comment.

Comment: Just a quick comment: on systems with 32-bit integers, you cannot use this implementation to calculate 14! because 14! is larger than the largest number representable in 32 bits. And on systems with 64-bit integers, 22! is as large as you'll be able to go.

Comment: @NikBougalis, right. A simple int factorial works well for example purposes though. My actual use case was quite different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

class factorial {
public:
  int operator()(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
      return 1;
    return n * (*this)(n-1);
  }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << factorial()(5) << std::endl;
}
```

Works fine for me. [Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3ae0c6e8fb2d091f64563c8e14a14fd5-b24e7def60aba11ee8094350eb73164e)

Answer (score 9):

You can either use the name of the overloaded operator:

```
operator()(n-1);
```

or invoke the operator on the current object:

```
(*this)(n-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

As `DyP` mentioned, you can call `(*this)(n-1)`. However, it's odd to read, so you'd be better off splitting it out into a seperate `calculate_factoral` method and calling that instead

Comment: If you want to give a nicer name to `*this`, then a local reference variable should be adequate.  e.g. `factorial& recurse = *this; return n * recurse(n-1);`  What you can't do is move it into a separate function named `factorial`, since that would have a naming conflict with a constructor.

Comment: @Ben - thanks, I missed that this class was also called factoral!

Answer (score 2):

As several people have pointed out you can just use the `(*this)(n - 1)` syntax.  But this syntax isn't exactly intuitive and a slightly better solution may be to factor out the actual implementation into another named method.

```
class factorial { 
public:
  int operator()(int n) {
    return impl(n);
  }
private:
  int impl(int n) { 
    // actual work here 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use explicit operator syntax:

```
class factorial {
  int operator()(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
      return 1;
    return n * operator()(n-1);
  }
};
```

Or dereference `this`:

```
class factorial {
  int operator()(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
      return 1;
    return n * (*this)(n-1);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

factorial surely?

I only know Java and a recursive factorial can be written as:

```
public class Factorial{

    public int factorial(int n) {
        return (n > 1) ? n * factorial(n-1) : 1;
    }
}
```

I assume the same principle applies.

Comment: But the function isn't called `factorial`; it's an overload of `operator()`.

Comment: Unfortunately knowing Java hasn't given you any experience with operator overloading, which is central to this question.

Comment: right, writing a function was simple; I was trying out function objects/operator overloading here.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't heard of operator overloading before.